# Formik - Reset form and display new values

Tags: reactjs, formik

I have a form and I would like to disable button:

- when no values are changed
- when the form is invalid
- while the form is being submitted

I have a button that looks like this:

```
<Button disabled={!(formik.isValid && formik.dirty) || formik.isSubmitting}>
    Submit
</Button>
```

In the `onSubmit` handler I have

```
onSubmit: (values, { setSubmitting, resetForm }) => {
    onFormSubmit(values)
    resetForm({ values })
    setTimeout(function(){
        setSubmitting(false)
    }, 1000);
}
```

It works "fine", but the problem is that `resetForm({ values })` sets the old values. Is there a way to reset the form and show the new values?

Comment: resetForm({ values: newValues })

Comment: @Viet that is what I tried, but it form displays old values

Comment: I saw your code are using old values

Answer (score 1):

### **You could reset to new values by adding `nextValues` to the function:**

**resetForm type**

```
resetForm(nextValues?: Values): void;
```

**So just put new values to the function like so:**

```
resetForm({ value1: "new value1", value2: "new value2" })
```

**Working example:**

[image: Edit Formik Form Reset (forked)]